# spring security does not redirect after successful login

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

i use spring security 3.2.5 for user authentication. after i provide user name and password in login page it is not redirecting to page mentioned in defaultSuccessUrl method and it just reloads login page.

following is my code please let me know what is wrong in this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception{
    webSecurity
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http 
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                //.usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery(
            "SELECT user_id, password, 'true' as enabled FROM scl_user_info   WHERE user_id = ?");
}
}
```

login.jsp

```
<form action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />" method="POST">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="j_username"/>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="j_password"/>
   <input type="checkbox" />
   <span class="lbl"> Remember Me</span>
   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
   <button type="submit" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
         <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>
         <span class="bigger-110">Login</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

HomeController

```
 @Controller
 public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String defaultPage() {
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
    return "login";
}

}
```

table columns

id, user_id, password

Comment: Enable debug logging to see what happens.

Comment: nothing is shown in log i could see only page gets reloaded after submit.

Answer (score 11):

try to use :

```
defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
```

it's works for me

Comment: Thanks very much ! In the article I followed as an example to implement authentification it was not specified and it was the only thing that did not work. thanks, post very usefull for me

Answer (score -2):

have a look at this:

```
  auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery(
                "SELECT username, password, 'true' as enabled FROM scl_user_info   WHERE user_id = ?");
```

table column should be username, password

Comment: this code not looking like spring security. for this method protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception