# Java Spring Boot Multiple Page Redirect Issue On Login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

[image: post-second login][image: post-first login]Hello I'm developing a Java Spring Boot Web App and am having an issue where when the user correctly logs into the app, the app takes the user back to the login page for some reason rather than correctly taking them to the home page. However, once the user logs in correctly that first time (even though they've been taken back to the login page), they are able to sign out and if they try to log back in, they are correctly taken to the "/home" page. I'm not sure why this isn't happening correctly on the first try, however. The different pieces of code that are not working together properly are as follows: 1. my configure() method, which you can see should be redirecting the user to "/home" on a successful login. 2. the @RequestMapping functions in my AuthController. 3. my tiles.xml file

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/login", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
        }
```

```
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    String admin() {
        return "app.login";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/")
    String login() {
        return "app.login";
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">


<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="app.default" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="bcore Hardware" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="app.home" extends="app.default">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/home.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <!-- WILL NEED ITS OWN TEMPLATE -->
  <definition name="app.login" extends="app.default">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/login.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <!-- WILL NEED ITS OWN TEMPLATE -->
  <definition name="app.newRecord" extends="app.default">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/newRecord.jsp" />
  </definition>


  <definition name="app.viewRecord" extends="app.default">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/viewRecord.jsp" />
  </definition>


  <definition name="app.editRecord" extends="app.default">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/editRecord.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="app.account" extends="app.default">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/account.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="app.editAccount" extends="app.default">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/editAccount.jsp" />
  </definition>


  <definition name="app.register" extends="app.default">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/register.jsp" />
  </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

I want it structured so that the user, while not logged in, only has access to the login page. Then on successful login, they are redirected to the home page with different privileges to view  based on roles, which is working correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After successful login you are getting redirected to /home correctly, is it? If yes, after /home which url are you trying to access.

Comment: After first successful login after starting the app, I am redirected to "/login" rather than "/home" like I want to happen. After the second succesful login and from there on, I am correctly redirected to "/home". I just don't know why I am redirected to "/login" after the first succesful attempt.

Comment: Shared code seems to works, can you share the GitHub link if possible

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. How did you test it? Link?

Comment: Can you check the requests in Network tab from first login attempt and share the image

Comment: I've shared in the question above. As you can see, after the first login, I'm redirected to the login screen again, but after the second, I'm sent to the home page.

Comment: could you shares a minimal reproducible code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I may have found the answer, although I'm not 100% sure I understand the documentation. All I did was change "defaultSuccessUrl("/home")" to "defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)", and this gave me the result I needed. Documentation on this can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#defaultSuccessUrl-java.lang.String-boolean-

And another similar post can be found here: [spring security does not redirect after successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405863/spring-security-does-not-redirect-after-successful-login)

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation ***`defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl, boolean alwaysUse)`***

Specifies where users will go after authenticating successfully if they have not visited a secured page prior to authenticating or alwaysUse is true.

---

Now let's explore some code,

[`AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java) consists of methods `defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl)` and  `defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl, boolean alwaysUse)`

**[`1.defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6e0d2f33244361eb8da5e4dd67f275bb4580372b/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java#L115)**

This is a shortcut for calling *defaultSuccessUrl(String).*

```
public final T defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl) {
    return defaultSuccessUrl(defaultSuccessUrl, false);
}
```

**[`2. defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl, boolean alwaysUse)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6e0d2f33244361eb8da5e4dd67f275bb4580372b/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java#L130)**

```
public final T defaultSuccessUrl(String defaultSuccessUrl, boolean alwaysUse) {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        handler.setDefaultTargetUrl(defaultSuccessUrl);
        handler.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(alwaysUse);
        this.defaultSuccessHandler = handler;
        return successHandler(handler);
    }
```

---

As we may see method 1 ultimately calls method 2 with *alwaysUse as false*, by using methods 2 with *alwaysUse as true* we are explicitly setting the parameter which is further used in [`SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java) as follows

```
if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
        || (targetUrlParameter != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParameter)))) {
    requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring won't redirect you based on your role, you have to manage redirect manually,
It will only give you **access** to it.

Take a look:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 
 http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
  .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
  .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
  .and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/redirect") //endpoint to manage redirects
  .and().logout()
  .permitAll();
}
```

---

**Managing redirects** `/redirect`

```java
@GetMapping("/redirect")
public void getRedirect(HttpServletResponse resp, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
 
 System.out.println("Auth: " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());

 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 System.out.println("Principal: " + auth.getPrincipal());
 System.out.println("Authorities: " + auth.getAuthorities()); //get it from here OR
 System.out.println(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_USER")); // get it from Here as WELL (ONLY IF YOU HAVE A REQUEST)

 if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_USER")) {
  resp.sendRedirect("/user");
 } else if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
  resp.sendRedirect("/admin");
 }
}
```

Keep in mind there are scope differences

- `hasRole()` results in `Authorities: [ROLE_ADMIN]`
- `hasAuthority()` results in `Authorities: [ADMIN]`

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is causing the problem. But you can try avoiding the default lines of login and successUrl and replace them by `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()` and creating a controller of the Post /login.

```
@PostMapping("login")
    public String login(@RequestBody UserDTO user) { ... }
```

#### Note

I would change annotation in your login method to specify the GET.

`@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

or

`@GetMapping("login")` which is more recommended (Be careful on the '/' character I think in this one you don't need it)

Hope it helps!